# withinMiles not working with Parse PFGeopoint query in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, coordinates

I am trying to find all users within a certain distance of the current user's PFGeopoint. The query returns objects when using:

query!.whereKey("addressPoint", nearGeoPoint: userGeopoint)

but it returns no objects when using:

query!.whereKey("addressPoint", nearGeoPoint: userGeopoint, withinMiles: 100)

There are almost 20 users within 100 miles of the simulator's position in Cupertino, so that isn't the issue.

Here is the full code:

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

var userGeopoint = PFGeoPoint()

```
    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
        (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            userGeopoint = geoPoint!
            //print(userGeopoint)
        }
    }

    let query = PFUser.query()
    query!.whereKey("addressPoint", nearGeoPoint: userGeopoint, withinMiles: 1000)
    query!.limit = 20
    query!.orderByDescending("updatedAt")
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

        if let users = objects {
        for object in users {
                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                    if user != PFUser.currentUser() {
                        print(user["addressPoint"])
                        }
                    }
            }
```

}
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        })
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get user location it can take couple seconds, that is why **PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground** is not running on the main thread, put your query inside that and it will work... Also i think that the query by **distance is limited** only to 100 Miles

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
    (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let query = PFUser.query()
        query!.whereKey("addressPoint", nearGeoPoint: geoPoint, withinMiles: 100)
        //... rest of the query
    }
}
```